# Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead with 1 object that has comma separated Key:Values

Tags: json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

Not sure if anyone has run into this situation.  I have an endpoint I'm using for my typeahead that returns 1 object with a list of key:values.  A normal response will look like this:

```
{
 "BK-021":"BK-021",
 "BK-058":"BK-058",
 "BK-068":"BK-068",
 "BK-088":"BK-088",
 "bk-1":"bk-1",
 "BK-10":"BK-10"
}
```

If I search for "BK" in this case for the example above, the endpoint returns the same key name as the value.  This makes it seemingly impossible to plug into typeahead since its not returning a list of objects with a known KEY and doesn't separate the list into multiple objects either. I've been wracking my brain over this for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with a bit of underscore to help.  My request now looks like this:

```
$scope.getCode = function(val) {
  return $http.get('http://urlhere'+val)
  .then(function(response){
    var sorted = response.data;
    var sortedObject = _.values(sorted);
    return sortedObject;
  });
};
```

By using _.values I'm able to just transform the object into a basic array and print all results.  Works perfectly!